# How can I "bootstrap" an install4j Uprade installation of a non-install4j software install?

Tags: installation, install4j

I've all but settled on install4j as my install package of choice for my project.  Among many other advantages, it's built-in support for Upgrades out-classes the field as far as I can tell.  I do have a curious question though ..

Is there a best practice or any reusable code for supporting the notion of "bootstrapping" an install4j installer with any metadata it needs to support Upgrading an older release of a product that was installed with "home grown" installation mechanisms?

As is the case with many projects I'd assume, ours is one that has been around for years and has a mishmash of InstallShield installers for Windows and BASH scripts for Unix.  We're using install4j to consolidate all of that.

Some possible interesting follow-up questions might be:
1.  Is there a way I can set the value returned from isUpgradeInstallation() in the API?
2.  If I drop a file in a .install4j directory with the Application ID embedded in my new installer can install4j run with it?

Any ideas/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you would add custom logic to handle the case of legacy upgrades.

However, you can convert your legacy installation to a "fake" install4j installation by creating an .install4j directory in the old installation directory containing an `i4jparams.conf` file. In that fake config file the only important information is the version information and the application ID, you can delete everything else.

Then `context.isUpdateInstallation()` will return true.